# how to get parameter which is not defined in function

Tags: javascript

I have defined 2 parameter in main function but at the time of calling it has 4 parameter. so question is how to get parameter which is not defined. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nJG2C/)

```
function test(a,b)
{
 alert(a)   
 alert(b)    
}
test(1,2,5,4)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) is the way to go:

```
function test(a, b) {
    alert( arguments[2] );

    // prints 5
}

test(1, 2, 5, 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the function like this:

```
function test() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    console.log(arguments[i]);
  }
}

test(1);
test(1,2);
test(1,2....);

Works for dynamic number of arguments.
```